# programación for y switch

Tags: bucle-for, switch

/* EJERCICIO

En la tienda el redentor quieren un programa para ingresar todos sus productos
los cuales son(gaseosas, sopas, galletas, golosinas, canela)
los productos tienen que llevar su fecha de vencimiento y un comentario de que tal les pareció en el producto.
*/
esto es lo que llevo hasta ahorita pero no se si voy bien o como es de verdad

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string productos[5];

    for ( int i=0; i < 5 ; i++){
        cout<<"INGRESE LOS NOMBRES DE LOS PRODUCTOS:  ";
        cin>>productos[i];
        
        switch ( i < 5  )
        {
            case 1: cout<< " VENCE EL 09/06/2021";
            cout<<" LAS GASEOSAS SON MUY BUENAS \n"; break;
            case 2: cout<< " VENCE EL 14/02/2022";
            cout<<" LA SOPA NO ME GUSTA \n"; break;
            case 3: cout<< " VENCE EL 23/10/2028";
            cout<<" LAS GALLETAS ESTAN EN PEDAZOS \n"; break;
            case 4: cout<< " VENCE EL 31/12/2056";
            cout<<" LAS GOLOSINAS ESTAN MUY CARAS \n"; break;
            case 5: cout<< " VENCE EL 07/05/2029";
            cout<<" LA CANELA HUELE RICO"; break;
            default: cout<<"NO SE ENCUENTRA EN NUESTRA TIENDA "; break;
            
        }
    }   
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: pues cumple con el enunciado per sé

Comment: pero no me funciona, me tira el mismo enunciado para cada producto, que debo hacer

Comment: necesito ayuda ,no soy buena en esto

Comment: no sé de C++ (eso creo que es), pero el switch no debe de llevar el signo menor qué, o sí?

Answer (score 1):

El switch es un tipo de control de selección, no tiene signo de comparación (=,<,>); eso sería el error en tu código, entonces la forma correcta sería:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string productos[5];

    for ( int i=1; i <= 5 ; i++){
        cout<<"INGRESE LOS NOMBRES DE LOS PRODUCTOS:  ";
        cin>>productos[i];        
        
        switch (i )
        {
            case 1: cout<< " VENCE EL 09/06/2021\n";
            cout<<" LAS GASEOSAS SON MUY BUENAS \n"; break;
            case 2: cout<< " VENCE EL 14/02/2022";
            cout<<" LA SOPA NO ME GUSTA \n"; break;
            case 3: cout<< " VENCE EL 23/10/2028";
            cout<<" LAS GALLETAS ESTAN EN PEDAZOS \n"; break;
            case 4: cout<< " VENCE EL 31/12/2056";
            cout<<" LAS GOLOSINAS ESTAN MUY CARAS \n"; break;
            case 5: cout<< " VENCE EL 07/05/2029";
            cout<<" LA CANELA HUELE RICO"; break;
            default: cout<<"NO SE ENCUENTRA EN NUESTRA TIENDA "; break;            
        }        
        cout<<endl;
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias.